# Are the crown given to the first horseman in Revelation 6:2 and the crown in Isaiah 28:1 the same kinds of crowns?

Tags: revelation, isaiah

Are the crown given to the first horseman in Revelation 6:2 and the crown of the drunkards of Ephraim given to the strong one in Isaiah 28:1 the same kinds of crowns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word used in Rev 6:2 is "stephanos", a "chaplet" (see David Bentley Hart's translation and W E Vine Expository dictionary) of (usually) laurel leaves made into a wreath given to victors at Olympic games.  In the LXX version of Isa 28, the same word is used.  The NIV correctly translates this as "wreath".

Note that in Rev 6 the "stephanos" signifies victory (Gr: "nike") as the rider goes "conquering and to conquer".  In Isa 28 the wreath of the drunkards symbolises the fertile valley (v1, v4, etc) about to be despoiled, and is contrasted with the LORD Almighty who will become the victory wreath of the remnant (v5).

Answer (score 0):

Revelation 14:14 (the same person as it Rev. 6:2)
Then I saw, and look! a white cloud, and seated on the cloud was someone like a son of man [Jesus], with a golden crown on his head and a sharp sickle in his hand.

Isa. 28:1 talks of the 10 tribe kingdom, also called Ephraim, which was acting as if drunk with power and pride when making friends with Syria and other nations, eneimes of God and judah the 2 tribe kingdom, thus a false crown of power!!

ethos